# In Entity Framework Code First for how do I create new records for two related 1 to common M posted data relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am using EF Code First 5.
I have 3 entities/POCO classes - Proposal, Document and Template that are related.
Proposal has a M to M relationship with Document table.
Template has a M to M relationship with Document table.

Here are my POCO C# classes

```
public class Document {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Proposal> Proposals { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}

public class Proposal {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Template {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

In my front end MVC app the user creates a proposal and adds documents to it.
I then receive the posted data in my MVC action method and add all the document to the proposal Documents collection

```
 proposal.Description = model.Description;
 proposal.Documents = GetDocumentsFromPostedFiles(model.Files);
 db.Entry(proposal).State = EntityState.Added;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

This work perfectly as the documents get assigned unique ids when saving to the db and are linked to my proposal.

However in the same screen with the same action the user has the option to save the documents he adds to the proposal to a new template. 
So I want the Template table to get the reference the same documents that is being added to the Proposal in my one MVC action method.
I receive the posted data 
 - the 1 Proposal. 
 - Many Documents 
 - the new Template Title, Description
so what I want to update is all 3 tables with this posted data.

I tried the following:

```
 proposal.Description = model.Description;
 proposal.Documents = GetDocumentsFromPostedFiles(model.Files);

 template.Description = model.TemplateDescription;
 template.Documents = proposal.Documents();

 db.Entry(proposal).State = EntityState.Added;
 db.Entry(template).State = EntityState.Added;   

 db.SaveChanges();
```

This obviously updates incorrectly since the new unadded Documents have a Document id not set (value is default of 0) since the database will set it in the database after the db.SaveChanges so when I run it the templates' document ids' are incorrectly saved as 0.

How do I tell Entity Framework the template object's documents are related to the just added proposal documents? 
I use the starting point of the 1 to M of either proposal or template to tell entity framework to add them to the database but as in my case since  I have two 1 to M relationships how do I tell EF that the two M tables are in fact the same table when I do my initial db.SaveChanges?

Any other possible solution for this? I can only think of saving the proposal to the database first and  reading all the just added documents with their primary key created ids from the database and then adding them to my Template. 
This would result in a db.SaveChanges , Linq db Fetch and db.SaveChanges again where I would rather want to do this in one db.SaveChanges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `SaveChanges()` after the proposal initialization:

```
proposal.Description = model.Description;
proposal.Documents = GetDocumentsFromPostedFiles(model.Files);

db.Entry(proposal).State = EntityState.Added;
db.SaveChanges();

template.Description = model.TemplateDescription;
template.Documents = proposal.Documents;

db.Entry(template).State = EntityState.Added;   
db.SaveChanges();
```